# How to add chrome extension by using the windows registry?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I did the things in [Google Document](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html#registry).

I use 64bit Windows 7, so I add path and version value in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\jhfbfhflacclgdglfjekfhhnbdhokaad

(jhfbfhflacclgdglfjekfhhnbdhokaad : my extension's ID

path value : C:\Users\realstorm103\Downloads\set_page_color\set_page_color.crx(REG_SZ)

version value : 2.0.1.2(REG_SZ)
)

But nothing is changed.

Should I do anything else to add chrome extension with using registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `path` value should point directly to the CRX file, so perhaps: `C:\Users\realstorm103\Downloads\set_page_color\set_page_color\extension.crx`.

Comment: Sorry. It's my mistake when i wrote this question. I did it correctly but it didn't work. Is there any other mistakes?

Answer (score 2):

As per this document - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions -
it is no longer possible to register "local" extensions, but only "published" ones.

"In the Windows registry, the update_URL must point to the Chrome Web Store where the extension is hosted."